# Attaching / Detaching Listeners in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a component which, depending on its prop (`listId`) listens to a different document in a Firestore database.

However, when I update the component to use a new `listId`, it still uses the previous listener.

What's the correct way to detach the old listener and start a new one when the component receives new props?

Some code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { db } from '../api/firebase';

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [],
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const { listId } = this.props;
    db.collection(`lists/${listId}/todos`).onSnapshot((doc) => {
       const todos = [];

       doc.forEach((t) => {
         todos.push(t.data());
       });

       this.setState({ todos });
     });
   };

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    return (
        {todos.map(t => <li>{t.title}</li>)}
    );
  }
}

TodoList.propTypes = {
  listId: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default TodoList;
```

I've tried using `componentWillUnmount()` but the component never actually unmounts, it just receives new props from the parent.

I suspect that I need something like `getDerivedStateFromProps()`, but I'm not sure how to handle attaching / detaching the listener correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a `key` prop to the `TodoList` lets the component behave as it should.